# many_to_many, sti and will paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-table-inheritance, will-paginate

i have following code

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, :through => :categorizations
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
end

class NewsArticle < Post
end
```

ok, looks good. I'me trying to get all NewsArticle's from category

```
@news_articles = NewsArticle.paginate_by_category_id params[:category],
  :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10,
  :order => 'posts.created_at DESC'
```

and i see

```
 NoMethodError in News articlesController#category

undefined method `find_all_by_category' for #<Class:0x103cb05d0>
```

what can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add named scopes and use them with paginate:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  named_scope :newest, :order => 'posts.created_at DESC'
  named_scope :by_category, lambda { |category_id| { 
    :joins => :categories,
    :conditions => ['categories.category_id = ?', category_id]
  } }
end

@news_articles = NewsArticle.newest.by_category(params[:category]).paginate(
  :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
  )
```

Comment: looks much better :)) thanks :) but unfortunately posts cannot be found if category model is under friendly_id (http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) :(

PS: small correction of your example - 
     :conditions => ['categories.id = ?', category_id]

Comment: I have updated your example a little and now it works fine
      @category = Category.find params[:category]
      @news_articles = NewsArticle.newest.by_category(@category.id) .....

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
@news_articles = NewsArticle.paginate(:conditions => { :category_id => params[:category_id].to_i }, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'posts.created_at DESC')
```

Are you passing the category id as `params[:category]` or `params[:category_id]`?  If you're not sure you can `debug(params)` in your view.

Comment: better, but now it looks like "no such column: posts.category_id"

i'm passing category id as params[:category]

Comment: Try switching to :order => :category_id